# Using dx/dy to locate y-parallel tangent

Tags: calculus

**The curve $C$ has equation 
$$y=x^2+0.2sin(x+y)$$
Show that $C$ has no tangent(no point where $dy/dx=∞$), that is parallel to the y axis.**

**Attempt**
$1=2x\frac{dx}{dy}+0.2cos(x+y)(1+\frac{dx}{dy})$

For a tangent to be parallel to y-axis,

$\frac{dx}{dy}=0$

$1=0.2cos(x+y)$

$cos(x+y)=5$

No value of $(x,y)$ exist for which $cos(x+y)>1$, hence no y-axis parallel tangent.

**Confusion**
Never been taught or encountered $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and thus I am having doubts over the validity of the solution.

Can somebody please verify it?

Comment: I have been taught differentiation but only with respect to x,t,θ. Never found a question where I was suppose to differentiate x with respect to y. Can you tell me why my solution is incorrect?

Comment: What I mean is I am aware of implicit differentiation, many of the stuff, but never encountered a situation where use of dx/dy was useful. So I know how to calculate it but never needed to calculate it. Can you please tell me the flaw in my solution?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am not expecting $dx/dy$ to give the slope. And yes I want to measure the run over rise because for a vertical line, run remains zero whereas the rise continues to increase, hence $dx/dy=0$.

Comment: your solutions seems fine to me. Also, you are using, if you didn't notice, implicit differentiation, to find $\frac{dx}{dy}$. There may be other ways to solve this problem, but re answering your question, your solution is valid.

Comment: @Mirko I am just concerned whether $dx/dy=0$ for a vertical line.

Comment: yes, just like $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ for a horizontal line

Comment: @Mirko Okay thank you very much.

Comment: yeah ur good!!!

Comment: @SakethMalyala Lol thanks